# Codeigniter display error next to field using

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I display each error next to input field, or only one error for all fields (like "all fields are required") down below? I prefer each error next to input.

1. View: I'm using form_open and later form_input. form_eror doesn't work.

   ```
   // INPUT FORM FOR PRODUCT INSERT

   // Form open
   echo form_open('insert_product',array('id' =>'form')); 

   //all form inputs

   // Name
   echo form_label('Name  ','name');
   $name = array(
       'name'        => 'productName',
       'id'          => 'productName',
       'placeholder' => 'Enter product name',

   );
   echo form_input($name,  set_value('name'));
   echo form_error('name');
   ```
2. Controller validation rules in array:

   ```
   // Define validation rules for form inputs
   $validation_rules = array(
       //Name
       array(
           'field' => 'productName',
           'label' => 'Product name',
           'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]'   
       ),
   ```
3. Validation check in controller :

   ```
   //Check validation
   if ( $this->form_validation->run() == true ) {

        //Preparing input data, keys of array are the same as fields in database table
           $data = array(
               'Name'            => $this->input->post('productName'),
               'Description'     => $this->input->post('productDescription'),
               'Production_date' => date('Y-m-d',  strtotime( $this->input->post('productProduction_date' ))),
               'Expiry_date'     => date('Y-m-d',  strtotime( $this->input->post('productExpiry_date' ))),
               'Price'           => $this->input->post('productPrice'),
               'Currency'        => $this->input->post('productCurrency'),
               'EAN_code'        => $this->input->post('productEAN_code'),
               'Weight'          => $this->input->post('productWeight'),
               'Weight_unit'     => $this->input->post('productWeight_unit')
           );

           //Transfer data to model and get message from model
          $row = $this->ProductModel->insert_product($data);

           //get answer
           if ($row) {
              echo "Product successfully added to database";
           }else {
               echo 'There was an error inserting data in database '.json_encode($row);
           }

   }
   else {

       echo validation_errors();
   }
   ```

Comment: First off, you probably don't really want to `echo` from the controller. (Except to test ideas during development.) Second, it would be helpful to see where you are loading the view in the controller.

Comment: Hi I'm loading my view in index method, and im validating and calling model in insert method.

Comment: You don't show it so I have to ask, how/where are the rules being set? I assume that somewhere you're calling `$this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules );` That should probably happen in the insert method.

Comment: Rules are set at point 2 in array..i didnt post rules for 10 inputs.

Comment: I can see where the rules are defined. But where/how are you using the array? As far as I can tell, you need to call `$this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules );` somewhere in the function where `form_validation->run()` is called.